# How to trigger a change in a PHP server from a date in a SQL db

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento2

I have an e-commerce site (based on magento2) with products on it that need to be available between certain dates. I have saved the specific start and end dates in a mysql db but now need to trigger the enabling/disabling of a product when the time is reached. How can I have a live link between the two without setting up a cron job that runs every second to edit the status?

Comment: Why not put the dates in the product record and amend the search to only show ACTIVE products

Answer (score 1):

"I need a CRON every second" for a MySQL problem means your actually need a `VIEW` (or eventually a `TRIGGER` for heaviest cases).

Assuming you have `product.startDate` and `product.endDate` columns, along with a `product.isEnabled`.
Then create the following `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW `productView` AS SELECT 
    startDate AS startDate,
    endDate AS endDate, 
    (isEnabled AND NOW() BETWEEN startDate AND endDate) AS isEnabled
FROM product
```

And use this `VIEW` in your code (`SELECT p.isEnaled FROM productView`). In case you cannot update the PHP using code, just rename the table (for `productTable`) and use `product` AS the view's name.